# How to get a resource id with a known resource name?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I want to access a resource like a String or a Drawable by its name and not its int id.

Which method would I use for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

It will be something like:

`R.drawable.resourcename`

Make sure you don't have the `Android.R` namespace imported as it can confuse Eclipse (if that's what you're using).

If that doesn't work, you can always use a context's `getResources` method ...

```
Drawable resImg = this.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.resource);
```

Where `this.context` is intialised as an `Activity`, `Service` or any other `Context` subclass.

**Update:**

If it's the name you want, the `Resources` class (returned by `getResources()`) has a `getResourceName(int)` method, and a `getResourceTypeName(int)`?

**Update 2**:

The `Resources` class has this method:

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Which returns the integer of the specified resource name, type & package.

Comment: Thankq like this i want and i want to get drawable resource id.how i wil to it

Comment: As maragues has suggested, it would be like `this.context.getResources().getIdentifier("package:type/entry", null, null);` where `"package:type/entry"` would be for example, `"com.your.package:drawable/resourcename"` ?

Answer (score 378):

If I understood right, this is what you want

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Where "this" is an Activity, written just to clarify.

In case you want a String in strings.xml or an identifier of a UI element, substitute "drawable"

```
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfResource", "id", this.getPackageName());
```

I warn you, this way of obtaining identifiers is really slow, use only where needed.

Link to official documentation: [Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 28):

### • `Kotlin Version` via `Extension Function`

To find a resource id by its name In Kotlin, add below snippet in a kotlin file:

**ExtensionFunctions.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Resources

fun Context.resIdByName(resIdName: String?, resType: String): Int {
    resIdName?.let {
        return resources.getIdentifier(it, resType, packageName)
    }
    throw Resources.NotFoundException()
}
```

### • `Usage`

Now all resource ids are accessible wherever you have a context reference using `resIdByName` method:

```
val drawableResId = context.resIdByName("ic_edit_black_24dp", "drawable")
val stringResId = context.resIdByName("title_home", "string")
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 27):

```
int resourceID = 
    this.getResources().getIdentifier("resource name", "resource type as mentioned in R.java",this.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 12):

```
// image from res/drawable
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_image", 
            "drawable", getPackageName());
// view
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource", 
            "id", getPackageName());

// string
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_string", 
            "string", getPackageName());
```

Comment: its returning dark mode res in light mode and wise versa

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you using my method to get a resource ID. It's Much more efficient, than using getIdentidier() method, which is slow.

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * @author Lonkly
 * @param variableName - name of drawable, e.g R.drawable.<b>image</b>
 * @param с - class of resource, e.g R.drawable.class or R.raw.class
 * @return integer id of resource
 */
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> с) {

    Field field = null;
    int resId = 0;
    try {
        field = с.getField(variableName);
        try {
            resId = field.getInt(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resId;

}
```

Comment: It will not work for all cases. For example if you have <string name="string.name">content</string> than the R.string class will have a string_name field. And your method will not work in this point.

Comment: Also your method is not fast actually. Because Java class serialization is never working quick.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin following works fine for me:

```
val id = resources.getIdentifier("your_resource_name", "drawable", context?.getPackageName())
```

If resource is place in mipmap folder, you can use parameter "mipmap" instead of "drawable".

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this in compose, here how you can do it:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val drawableId = remember(iconName) {
     //this block will re-calculate each time iconName has changed
     val resId by derivedStateOf {
        context.resources.getIdentifier(
             iconName,
             "drawable",
             context.packageName
            )
        }
    if (resId != 0) resId else R.drawable.some_fallback_icon //it doesn't throw an error instead resId becomes 0, so we need to check if 0 aka couldn't find the drawable.
   }
```

//then use drawableId

like `painterResource(id = drawableId)`

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @lonkly solution

1. see reflections and field accessibility
2. unnecessary variables

method:

```
/**
 * lookup a resource id by field name in static R.class 
 * 
 * @author - ceph3us
 * @param variableName - name of drawable, e.g R.drawable.<b>image</b>
 * @param с            - class of resource, e.g R.drawable.class or R.raw.class
 * @return integer id of resource
 */
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> с)
                     throws android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException {
    try {
        // lookup field in class 
        java.lang.reflect.Field field = с.getField(variableName);
        // always set access when using reflections  
        // preventing IllegalAccessException   
        field.setAccessible(true);
        // we can use here also Field.get() and do a cast 
        // receiver reference is null as it's static field 
        return field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // rethrow as not found ex
        throw new Resources.NotFoundException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this class](https://gist.github.com/brucetoo/48be42fa1387717547e2) very helpful to handle with resources. It has some defined methods to deal with dimens, colors, drawables and strings, like this one:

```
public static String getString(Context context, String stringId) {
    int sid = getStringId(context, stringId);
    if (sid > 0) {
        return context.getResources().getString(sid);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```