# Can't get string resource from R.string.*

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a SQlite table with two columns `_id` and `name`. For internationalization purpose I store the name like `R.string.today`
Now I want to get string resource associated with `R.string.today`:

```
String column = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(MainDb.NAME));

int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(column, "strings", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

String buttonText;

if (resId != 0)
{
  buttonText = getApplicationContext().getString(resId);
} else
{
  buttonText = "Resource is null!";
}
```

`resId` is always 0. Variable `column` have the right value, I've checked it with debugger. I've tried different variations in `resId`:

1. "string" instead of "strings" in defType.
2. Different variation of getResources like Resources.getSystem()...
3. Different variation of getPackageName()

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe I don't get your snippet but... why don't you just use `int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.MYSTRING)`?

Comment: getResources() requires activity context

       `String s = getResources().getString(R.string.today)`

Comment: Have you tried o use only `today` instead of `R.string.today`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be `string` instead of `strings`:

```
int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
           .getIdentifier(column, "string", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Check as well whether the value of `column` dsignates an identifier in your `strings.xml`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904531/get-resource-id-from-value) is a nice example.

**p.s.**: instead of `R.string.today` just store `today` or extract `store` from `R.string.today`.

```
Resources r = getResources();
r.getIdentifier("today", "string", getPackageName()));
r.getIdentifier("R.string.today", "string", getPackageName())); // doesn't work
r.getIdentifier("R.string.today".replaceAll(".*\\.", ""), "string", getPackageName()));
```

Only first and third work.

Comment: Interesting! I'll try it in the evening

Comment: How to use to use button Something like button = getApplicationContext().getId(resId);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = context.getString(R.string.resId);
```

Comment: resId means yourString. R.string.yourString