# How to reference resource file in a service?

Tags: android, service, android-resources, android-context

I have a service and I run a thread inside it. When I try to reference the strings.xml I receive "can't resolve symbol R", I am able to reference the same resources from another class in the application.

Please let me know how can I reference resources "strings.xml" correctly

**code**

```
SystemClock.sleep(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.int_short_max_wait_time));
```

Comment: Did you try rebuild project?

Comment: Please, have a look to [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503341/cant-get-string-resource-from-r-string) related to the same issue

Comment: @LudovicFrérot i solved it by qualifying the R class with the package name followed by the App name, as follows com.example.com.AppName

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by qualifying the R class with the package name followed by the App name, as follows, if your package is named: com.example.com and your App is named: AppTest, then qualify the R class as follows: com.example.com.AppTest.R.xx

**code**:

```
 SystemClock.sleep(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(com.example.com.AppTest.R.string.int_s
hort_max_wait_time));
```