# Creating media player with String source

Tags: android

My code is as follow:

```
cry = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bulbasaur);
```

What I want though is this:

```
cry = MediaPlayer.create(this, ("R.raw."+pokemon);
```

This way, whent he activity is passed a specific pokemons number, it will load the appropriate sound file.
Where pokemon is the name of the specific pokemons sound file.
I have tried using a Uri but I'm not sure that I'm doing it properly.

My OnCreate method can be seen below.
Thank you for your time.~

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Removes the title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Sets the screen size to full-screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.poke_layout);

    Bundle getId = getIntent().getExtras();
    //get the position integer from MenuActivity
    int position = getId.getInt("id");


    //Calls the function that initialises all UI items.
    initVars();
    //Set up variable from JSON field.
    getPokes(position);

    /**Defines the cry file**/
    cry = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bulbasaur);

    pPic.setImageResource(getImage(this, local));

    cry.start();
}
```

EDIT:
Just so that it is clear: I am loading a pokemons filename into the variable 'local' from a JSON file. I aim to use this variable to then load the appropriate file

Comment: I think what you want to do is make a map of either pokemon names or ids to R.raw.* ids. If it's few of them, might be easy enough to do an if/else or switch statement before creating the cry object. I think if you can reliably reproduce the other issue (about images), you should create another SO question. Sounds unrelated.

Comment: @Matt The image issue was to do with a JSON error. I fixed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get resource ID from value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904531/get-resource-id-from-value)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
static Map<String, Integer> idReferences = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
static {
   idReferences.put("Bulbasaur", R.raw.bulbasaur);
}

MediaPlayer.create(this, idReferences.get("Bulbasaur"));
```

References from the `R` file are auto generated so you don't want to reference them directly. Better to hold a list or a map of them and reference them indirectly. Like the above.

If you wanted a 'position' reference instead of a name, just use an `Integer` instead of a `String` as the key for the map.

References:

[Accessing Android Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

[What is a Java Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: This a good answer, but maybe a it would be good to add a bit of description/explanation for people who might not know what a Map is.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends like so ;-)