# Android SDK - get R.id (int) of a string value

Tags: android

Lets say I have an xml file called test1.xml in String xmlFile = "test1.xml" format.  How can I get the R.id.test1 value of it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the `getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)` method within the `Resources` class.  Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

However this approach is quite slow, note the following from the docs:

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Here is another similar question: [get resource id by passing name as a parameter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/get-resource-id-by-passing-name-as-a-parameter-in-android)