# Playing raw file based on String

Tags: android, galaxy

I have a simple program where I generate random numbers, and use these to return an element from an array.  Based on this array element, I want to play a sound file.  For example:  The random element that was returned was "Am".  I now want to play the file "am.ogg".  But you cant just throw a string in for the resourceId.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be duplicate of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026215/android-sdk-get-r-id-int-of-a-string-value) (which by the way is also duplicate). Except for using this method you can also use reflection on the R class (second also not good option). The best option is the one in which the list of ids you will be interested in can be determined in the code. Basically you define map mapping every string to the corresponding `R.id` variable (`int`). However, I am not quite sure this will be your case.

Comment: nevermind, got it to work - I used the getResources(full_name,null,null) instead of getResources(name,folder,package)