# Android getIdentifier doesn't work for string?

Tags: android

I really don't know why but I can't retrieve the Id of a String.

This is my code:

```
int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
           .getIdentifier("About_EmailPrompt", "string", "com.yoki.android.cat");
```

But it works perfectly for all other classes of R file:

```
int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
           .getIdentifier("arrow","drawable", "com.yoki.android.cat");
```

So I really don't understand what's going on here, any ideas ?

Comment: Did you tried to execute "clean" on the project? May be some old cache is messing up the things...

Comment: Did you check whether `About_EmailPrompt` is defined in `R.java` generated file?

Answer (score 19):

This code looks like correct code:

```
int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("About_EmailPrompt", "string", "com.yoki.android.cat");
```

and it should work, but if not I advise you do not try to get around this and try to understand Why it doesn't work:

1) First of all try to find next declarated field in your project/projects:

```
About_EmailPrompt
```

if you are using eclips you should press *Ctrl+H* and open *Java Search* tab
[image: Java Search Dialog]

If you get results for searching go to step 2 otherwise go to step 3

2) You should get result as hierarchy

> ```
> <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>
>     -- R
>      -- string
>          -- About_EmailPrompt
> ```

2.1) check you write correct package name in your code

```
.getIdentifier("About_EmailPrompt", "string", <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>);
```

2.2) check you use just latin symbols in your literal strings:

```
"About_EmailPrompt"
```

and

```
"string"
```

2.3) check you use just latin symbols in `name` attribute in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="About_EmailPrompt">SOME_VALUE</string>
```

3) If you have no search result

3.1) check you use just latin symbols in your literal string:

```
"About_EmailPrompt"
```

3.2) check you use just latin symbols in `name` attribute in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="About_EmailPrompt">SOME_VALUE</string>
```

3.3) Do clean and build for all projects you have

P.S. If this does not help you, try to restart your IDE (sometimes eclipse generate R.java incorrectly until restarting)

Comment: Thank god i finally found someone who is able to do this. I could cry right now. THANKS

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative approach, you can use reflection:

```
R.string.class.getField("string_name").getInt(null);
```

Which essentially does the trick by getting a field of the class by name and then getting the integer value.

We pass null as the object because all the resources generated field are static and therefore not part of an object.

You may need to handle a few exceptions (NoSuchFieldException, etc) in case you made a typo, but it does work.

Comment: It still displays values like `#ff026cec`, not the real String.

Comment: Yes, it is an int, which is an id for a resource and therefore what was asked. You need to get the value using getString. The id is the same regardless the language, the string is not.

Comment: this looks like an elegant solution, I hope it works

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to get a working solution in my app. So, based on the original question, you would need to change it as the following:

```
int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
           .getIdentifier("com.yoki.android.cat:string/About_EmailPrompt", null, null);
```

This is another way of writing the getIdentifier() method but it seems to work this way.

Comment: getIdentifier takes 3 arguments. The resource name, resource type  and resource package.  The last two arguments are optional.  If the last two are not provided then the first argument has to include a full resource path.  This means the following two are the same:  

`int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
           .getIdentifier("com.yoki.android.cat:string/About_EmailPrompt", null, null);`  

same as:  
`int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
           .getIdentifier("About_EmailPrompt", "string", "com.yoki.android.cat");`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method to replace all the `getIdentifier`-calls. Else you have to mix two different approaches, which makes the code a little bit unclear.

This approach is similar to @shalafi's solution and uses reflection.

```
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {

    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(variableName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

and use it like this:

```
getResId("About_EmailPrompt", R.string.class); //or for other things
getResId("icon", R.drawable.class);
```

---

If you use

```
public static int getResStringId(String variableName) {
    try {
        Field idField = R.string.getDeclaredField(variableName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

it is even **faster** than `getIdentifier()` or the above solution. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4428288/2829009)

Answer (score -3):

I've this functions:

```
public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name)
    {
        Assert.assertNotNull(context);
        Assert.assertNotNull(name);

        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }

    public static int getString(Context context, String name)
    {
        Assert.assertNotNull(context);
        Assert.assertNotNull(name);

        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
                "strings", context.getPackageName());
    }
```

I think you should use strings instead of string

Comment: No, "string" should be fine. This is what works for me: `int id = getResources().getIdentifier(key, "string", getPackageName());`

Comment: Note that the identifier should be the same as how we refer to it. If it is `R.string.some_string`, then the second argument should be `"string"`, not `"strings"`.

Comment: It actually has to be "string" not "strings".