# How do I get Resource while passing "String" as a input rather than file?

Tags: java

I am facing a problem by getting org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource. from org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet by calling getResource(URI uri, boolean loadOnDemand) method of ResourceSet.

The problem is actually , this method takes "file" as an input, but I want to get Resource by giving "String" as a input.

For better understanding here is the code snippet.

```
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;

public static void main(String args[]){

    ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();
    Resource resource = set.getResource(URI.createURI("c:/users/input/inputFile.txt"),
                true);
}
```

I have a String as a input but this api takes only file..so is there any other api who takes String as a input and get the Resource????

I also do not want to make file.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You keep repeating that the method takes a File as input, but you also provide the signature of the method which is `getResource(URI uri, boolean loadOnDemand)`. I don't see any File in this method signature.

Comment: (URI.createURI("c:/users/input/inputFile.txt")  createURI take a file and locate it and pass it to getResource.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_string", "string", getPackageName());
```

Check this - [Android getIdentifier doesn't work for string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662316/android-getidentifier-doesnt-work-for-string)