# Specifying drawable resource id in a separate xml

Tags: android, drawable, imagebutton

I have an xml file that specifies a set of image button names. Also, I would like to specify the image resource id as an attribute of an xml node as shown below:

```
<button name="close" resLocation="R.drawable.close" />
```

I am parsing the xml in the code, I would like to set the image background for the dynamically created button using the resLocation attribute. Since resLocation is a string, I cannot convert to a Drawable object directly. Is there a way I can workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get `getResources().getIdentifier`:

```
String myResourceId = "close"; // Parsed from XML in your case
getResources().getIdentifier(myResourceId, "drawable", "com.my.package.name");
```

This would require your XML to be a little different:

```
<button name="close" resLocation="close" />
```

If you need to keep the R.type.id format in your XML, then you would just need to parse out the type and id:

```
String myResourceId = "R.drawable.close";
String[] resourceParts = myResourceId.split("\\.");
getResources().getIdentifier(resourceParts[2], resourceParts[1], "com.my.package.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<button name="close" resLocation="@drawable/close" />
```

or try

```
ImageButton imgButton=new ImageButton(this);

imgButton.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close));
```

Comment: This won't work because the resource identifiers are being read from an XML file (not a layout file) and will only be available as strings.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstand the question ..You could refer [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string[/link]

Comment: You could use reflection, but `getIdentifier` is the more clear way to do it and it's provided by the API so it's the sanctioned method for getting a resource from a string. The answer in that link even includes an edit that the author wasn't aware of `getIdentifier` at the time he answered.