# Is there a way to set setContentView(int id) dynamically?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-activity

I'd like to be able to loop through a list of xml layout files instead of having to specify a particular one in the setContentView argument.

Obviously the types are incorrect, but something like:

```
ArrayList<String> pages = new ArrayList<String>();
//(Where each of the xml pages are stored like R.layout.page1, R.layout.page2, etc)
setContentView(pages.get(0));
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What visual effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Sergey Rudchenko I just need to be able to load as many xml layout files as needed and loop through them to display without writing seperate activity classes for each of them.

Comment: This is probably some kind of a reusable activity class. But still unclear what is the aim.

Comment: Is this a kind of wizard? Are the page IDs really come to you as resource names (strings) in the runtime?

Comment: @Arhimed Yes you are right, it is meant to be a reusable activity class. I wouldnt like to divulge the aim though. Hopefully this doesn't limit how much you can help me!

Comment: @Sergey Rudchenko No they don't come as strings. They will always be called page1, page2, etc. I may just preload the Arraylist and do a catch block to carry on loading the activities until it cant find them anymore, but this seems quite redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) widget instead. Here is an [example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example).

It is cleaner to manage the content views and their children widgets this way.

Anyway, the resource IDs can be obtained from names using the [Resources.getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: This is great thank you, does exactly what I needed. It also allows me to go backwards and forwards between views very easily!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. it's possible. But two notes:

1. The ids are `int`s, not `String`s.
2. You need to manage the views inside them properly.

Comment: I know they are ints, but I don't know how to find out the int ids of the xml layout files dynamically.

Comment: @Neeta I thought you want to store the `id`s in a list.

Comment: @Neeta If I understand what you want, you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Comment: Thank you that link really helped a lot! I'll try to achieve what I want using this.

Answer (score 2):

In an application I have created I use the following code to set the image button to a particular resource:

```
imgBtnCard.setImageResource(this.getResources()
    .getIdentifier("com.twp.cptshitface:drawable/" +
        cardType + cardDetails[1] , null, null));
```

I would say that this is what you are looking for:

```
int resLayoutId = this.getResources().
    getIdentifier("your.package.namespace:layout/" +
    pages.get(0), null, null);

setContentView(resLayoutId);
// where pages.get(0) returns a string such as "main2"
```

I've quickly tested this code in the onCreateMethod.

*remember to clean your project if you add more layouts and/or resources so the id's are updated!*