# How to Use String as a ResourceID in Android

Tags: android

I've several `TextView`s or another component, doesn't matter. And the views have iteration ids like: `textView1, textView2, textView3` etc.

Simply I want to iterate ids by using **pre-string** values.

Psuedo example:

```
String pre_value = "textView";

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    String usable_resource_id = pre_value + Integer.toString(pre_value);
    // So how to use these id like R.id.textView1
    // Cast or something similar

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to use reflection: [look here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Comment: This what you are willing to do is called Metaprogramming (if you ever want to know how to search for it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Resources#getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the identifier from a string.

But if you are going to iterate over them, wouldn't it be easier to keep the ids in an array or a list?

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that `getIdentifier()` tends to be a little slow.

Comment: Yep `List` is more easier, right. Actually, I need dynamically changings. So does not fit for my app. Thanks for suggestion, it worked.