# How to get Resource(int) from String - Android

Tags: java, android, string, resources, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

```
String res = "R.drawable.image1";
```

I need to get it's INT id. Please help me!

Answer (score 27):

Use this to get resource id:

```
int picId = getResources().getIdentifier(picName, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Comment: there is nothing method like *getApplicationPackageName()*, without seeing the answer how one can upvote, ahh.

Comment: sorry my fault I have updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the `integer` then simply remove the quotes.

```
int id = R.drawable.image1; // instead of "R.drawable.image1"
```

That will give you the number.

Answer (score 2):

```
View view = findViewById(R.drawable.image1);
int id = view.getId();
```

Comment: This returns `R.drawable.image1`... You used an id you already had, then found it, then get it back

Comment: This does not answer the question of retriving an Id using a string because you hardcode it in findViewById