# How can I get a resource by name based on a string variable?

Tags: android

I want to  do

```
String childImg = "childIcon";
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.????, 0, 0, 0);
```

it's expecting an int but i have a string. how do i work around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, getting resource ID from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this to get drawable id

```
getResources().getIdentifier(childImg, "drawable", getPackageName())
```

Answer (score 1):

use `getIdentifier()`

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());
```

Comment: does not work for some reason. the image just doesn't come up

Comment: posible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
String childImg = "childIcon";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(childImg, "drawable", getPackageName())
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(id, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: yes, a little since it has to loop through all your resource elements to find the correct one.

Comment: So it's probably better to have an integer array in a singleton class if you're making many calls...right?

Comment: yes, indeed. But if you dont have huge list of resource elements then perhaps you may ignore the performance issue

Comment: does not work for some reason. the image just doesn't come up

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resources.getIdentifier(childImg), 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: does not work for some reason. the image just doesn't come up