# Android batch set ImageButton Visibility

Tags: android, view, visibility, imagebutton, batch-processing

I want to hide all image ImageButton on the app launch;

how can I archive that? here's the code:

```
ImageButton imgBtn[];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
                hideBtn();
}

private void hideBtn(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            imgBtn[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById("R.id.myBTN"+[i]);
            imgBtn[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

**Update**
I changed the hideBtn method then I got Force Close while testing

```
 -159   private void hideBtn(){
 -160       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 -161           int id = getResources().getIdentifier("myBTN"+i,"id", "com.my.app");
 -162           imgBtn[i] = (ImageButton)findViewById(id);
 -163           imgBtn[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
 -164       }
 -165   }
```

Crash log cat report:

```
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463):    at com.my.app.Main.hideBtn(Main.java:162)
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463):    at com.my.app.Main.onCreate(Main.java:61)
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5108)
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
03-18 16:46:05.125: E/AndroidRuntime(19463):    ... 11 more
```

Update :
this is the xml code:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myBTN1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myBTN2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myBTN1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myBTN1"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myBTN3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myBTN2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myBTN2"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

Comment: You cant get the resource id from a string that way. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10116885/2116951

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` needs the argument of type int but you are passing type of string.
You need to get the resource id first.

you can use getIdentifier method of resource class to get the id, check this [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

do like this

```
int id=getResources().getIdentifier("myBTN"+[i], "id", "com.mypackage.myapp");
```

then

```
imgBtn[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(id);
```

Comment: "myBTN"+[i] should be "myBTN"+i ?

Comment: @jkjk just copy paste your code, it should be i remove square brackets

Comment: @jkjk sorry for the late reply...please post logcat trace..And also xml file... may be your i values from 1 to 7  I think