# How to get id of the resource of the specified name?

Tags: android, resource-id

I have files in the folder `drawable` which are named in one way:

```
v[versionNumber]i[nameOfFile]
```

Example: `v1i2`

And in the activity code I have a

```
String fileName = "v1i2;//name of the desired resource id
int drawableId = GETTHISID(fileName);
```

Is it possible to get id of this drawableId resource?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, getting resource ID from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("v"+i+"i"+i,"drawable", getPackageName()); 
}
```