# Store multi Drawable in an ArrayList with For cycle

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist, drawable

I have a lot of images in my project named image_0, image_1, image_2 .... and currently, for storing them in an array, I use

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.image_0, R.drawable.image_1 ....};
```

But I have like 400 images and this is very ugly to see in the code so I'd like to use a for cycle like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>;
for(int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
   images.add(R.drawable.image_+"i");
}
```

But they are Int not String.. How can I do that ?

Comment: R.drawable.image_0 is string or integer?

Comment: Why are you storing image file name as integer?

Comment: @Rahul: these aren't strings, are ids - which are **integers**

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with it like this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>;
for(int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
   images.add(getResId(R.drawable.image_+"i", Drawable.class));
}

//method to convert String ID name into Integer value
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {

    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(variableName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

Original anwer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using reflection:

```
String name = "image_0";
final Field field = R.drawable.getField(name);
int id = field.getInt(null);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

Or using `Resources.getIdentifier()`:

```
String name = "image_0";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

For memory efficiency, I'd still recommend you to store the ids in a String array, and get the images only when you need them.