# Changing string resourses programmatically in android

Tags: android, string, textview

So i am making an app which has a lot of string.
 And what i am trying to make the same layout open just with different strings(the string fill the layout).
So i have strings called opna0,opna1,opna2... and up. When you press a button to access the string a number is passed to the class handling the layout and i want the class to take that number, add it to opna and get that recourse. 
So if i press button number 3 i want the textview to get the resourse

```
        "@strings/opna3"
```

but i have no idea how to do that so i was wondering if anyone got the answer?

Answer (score 3):

the simplest thing you can do is:

```
int stringId = getResources().getIdentifier("opna"+value, "string", getPackageName());
if (stringId > 0) {
  yourTextView.setText(stringId);
}
```

`getIdentifier()` returns a resource identifier for the given resource name.

Answer (score 0):

Use string array like this. load using resource

```
 <string-array name="array_items">
    <item name="item1">ONE</item>
    <item name="item2">TWO</item>
    <item name="item3">THREE</item>
</string-array>
```

load the strings and set the text depends on the click/index

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:
[Resources getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

you can see an example from a previous question like yours:
[Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to choose the string at runtime by storing the resource id in a `Map<Integer, Integer>`. Something like the following:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> mStringMap;
{
    mStringMap.put(0, R.string.opna0);
    mStringMap.put(1, R.string.opna1);
    mStringMap.put(2, R.string.opna2);
    mStringMap.put(3, R.string.opna3);
    ...
}

private void setStringFromResource(int id){
    if(mStringMap.containsKey(id)) mTextView.setText(mStringMap.get(id));
}
```

When a button is pressed, pass the corresponding integer value to `setStringFromResource()`. This method find the correct resource in `mStringMap` and then sets your `TextView`'s text to that resource. You won't be setting the string for your `TextView` in the layout xml, but rather at runtime programmatically.