# Access default value from custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to create my own `Preference` in which I want to give the user the choice to select the new value or to reset to default.

Therefore I need to "store" two values in one preference. 
I mean, I want to access the stored value and the default value (defined in XML) at the same time.

```
<my.custom.preference
    myCustomAttribute="R.color.someColor"
    android:defaultValue="@color/someColor"
    android:key="myPref"
/>
```

In my code, I read the value like this:

```
String value = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "myCustomAttribute");
```

The return value is `"R.color.someColor"`.

So, I tried to get the R-reference of this string, but this is the point where I'm failing.

```
int neededValue = ???
```

At the moment, I use a really bad workaround.
I search the selected `Preference` by key and set `neededValue` programmatically like this:

```
switch(getKey()) {
case "firstCustomPreference":
     neededColor = R.color.firstColor;
     break;
case "secondCustomPreference":
     neededColor = R.color.secondColor;
     break;
}
```

This does work, but I really hope there is a cleaner way of doing this.

So my question is: Is there a way to get the int value from the string `"R.color.someColor"`? Alternatively, is it possible to access the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way to get the int value from the String "R.color.someColor"?"

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("someColor", "color", getPackageName());
int color = getResources().getColor(resourceId);
```

Comment: Thanks. You helped me a lot.

Some further Information are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)