# Find specific string-array from a string value

Tags: java, android, arrays, mobile

I have multiple string-array in the file string.xml in my Android Project.

```
<string-array name="SS"> 
  <item>a</item> 
  <item>b</item> 
  <item>c</item>
</string-array> 
<string-array name="SV">
   <item>d</item> 
   <item>e</item> 
   <item>f</item> 
</string-array>
```

In my activity, I receive a value for string

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        mData = (HashMap<String, Object>) extras.get("data");
        this.id = (Integer) this.mData.get("id");
        this.name = (String) this.mData.get("name");

    }

   String[] mValues = getResources().getStringArray("");
```

"name" can be "SS" or "SV".

How can later find specific string-array item if "name" is "SS"?

NOTE: Currently I use

```
if(name.equals("SS")){
   String[] mValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SS);
}else if(name.equals("SV")){
   String[] mValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SV);
}
```

but, for me, is not a good idea and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this page can help you [Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

```
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {

try {
    Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(variableName);
    return idField.getInt(idField);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a map similar to

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // Replace Object with correct type
map.put("SS", R.array.SS);
map.put("SV", R.array.SV);

// ...

String[] mValues = getResources().getStringArray(map.get(name));
```