# Can I use variables in dot-notation in Java?

Tags: java, android, variables, for-loop

I am currently programming my first Android app and want to use a for-loop to add items to a View. This is done by Java:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++){
                items.add(new Item("Wallpaper " + i, R.drawable.wallpaper1));
            }
```

Am I able to use the variable "i" inside the "R.drawable.wallpaper_" call? The result should be something like:

```
items.add(new Item("Wallpaper " + i, R.drawable.wallpaper1));
items.add(new Item("Wallpaper " + i, R.drawable.wallpaper2));
items.add(new Item("Wallpaper " + i, R.drawable.wallpaper3));
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance 
Tafelbomber

Comment: Sorry but i dont really get it... how does an array help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Resources.getIdentifier(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for this, in a following way:

```
for (int i=0; i < 27; i++) {
    items.add(new Item("Wallpaper " + i, getResources().getIdentifier("wallpaper" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

For example, `getIdentifier("wallpaper" + 20, "drawable", getPackageName())` will resolve to `com.yourapp.R.drawable.drawable20`.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the app package, it's better to use something like `getContext().getPackageName()`. That way it will work properly even if the code is in a library shared by multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string%20%22%22) if you still want to access on this way using a `String`. A better way is using an array:

```
private int[] ids = new int[] {R.drawable.wallpaper1, R.drawable.wallpaper2, R.drawable.wallpaper3}

for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++){
   items.add(new Item("Wallpaper " + i, ids[i]));
}
```