# Android: How to reference TextView via String variable?

Tags: android

How can I reference TextView by using its id in a String variable, like:

xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />
```

code:

```
 public void changetext(String z){
    String x ="R.id.hello"+z;
    TextView y = (TextView) findViewById(x);
    y.setText("I've changed");
}
```

Comment: `findViewById` takes a resource a id which is an int value

Comment: Duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4427608/1465828)!

Comment: for more info check the source http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java

Comment: What is your main goal? What can we help you figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
public void changeText(String z){
    String x = "hello" + z;
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(x, "id", getPackageName());
    TextView y = (TextView) findViewById(id);
    y.setText("I've changed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your `public void changetext(String z)` method. Change to:

```
public void changeText(Activity a, int textViewId, String text) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) a.findViewById(textViewId);
    String x = "Hello:" + text; // or you can write "String x = text;" only if needed.
    tv.setText(x);
}
```

Here's how to use above method:

```
changeText(MyCurrentActivity.this, R.id.hello1, "Hi, this is my text.");
```

And the output will looks like this:

> Hello: Hi, this is my text.

Answer (score 0):

Define two variables of textviews

```
TextView txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt_one);
TextView txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt_two);         
setTextOnTextView("Good morning", txt1);
```

Method will settext on textview which you have passed to method

```
private void setTextOnTextView(String text, TextView txtView){
        String x ="Hello My Text"+" "+text;
        txtView.setText("I've changed");
}
```