# how to dynamically add image to imageView

Tags: android, android-activity

I was just wondering if any of you know how to do this. I have an activity that has a key value pair and I am trying to display an image if the key is equal to a string else don't show any image.

Does anyone know how or where to start with trying to get this to work right?

```
 final String splitedDouble[] = companyString.split(",,");

    String[] arrayOfString = { "Beard Vape Co;beard_vape_co", "two;zwei", "three;drei" };

    Hashtable<String, String> hashTable = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    for(String s: arrayOfString){
        String[] array = s.split(";");
        String sKey ="", sValue="";
        if(array.length > 1){
            sKey = array[0]; sValue = array[1];
            hashTable.put(sKey, sValue);
            if(sKey.toString().equals(liquidCompany)){
                imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt("R.drawable." + sValue.toString()));
            }
        }
```

This is what I have for the loop

Comment: Add some code to show what you are doing. BTW you can use View.setVisibility() to show/ hide your ImageView.

Comment: okay sounds good sorry about that I got the loop up that Im trying to make work but so far no luck

Comment: Ok. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Im not sure to be honest. What I am trying to do is with the arrayOfStrings as a key value pair so then I can pass the sValue to an Imageview for display if the title of the page is in this instance Beard Vape Co. but its not displaying the images at all

Comment: Proper use of stackoverflow:  At first, you just had an overly vague question. Should have been posted on some forum somewhere, not on a stackexchange site. Then you had a buggy piece of code that you didn't know why it didn't work. Still belongs on some forum, not on stackoverflow. The time to post on stackoverflow, is *after* you've worked on the code long enough to *pinpoint* a place where some feature of the language or OS doesn't work the way you think it should. Then you would have a *specific* question, whose answer *would be useful to others*. That's the intent of stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the solution to the problem that I was having I know its not the prettiest or the best code but it has the functionality that I was looking for. Thanks to everyone for all of the help with this issue!

```
String[] arrayOfString = { "Beard Vape Co.;beard_vape_co", "two;zwei", "three;drei" };

    List<String> sKeyArray = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> sValueArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s: arrayOfString) {
        String[] array = s.split(";");
        String sKey = "", sValue = "";
        if (array.length > 1) {
            sKey = array[0];
            sValue = array[1];
            sKeyArray.add(sKey);
            sValueArray.add(sValue);
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sKeyArray.size(); i++){
        if(sKeyArray.get(i).toString().contains(liquidCompany.trim().toString())){
            testingText.append(sKeyArray.get(i).toString());
            testingText.append(sValueArray.get(i).toString());
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(sValueArray.get(i).toString() , "drawable", getPackageName());
            imageView.setImageResource(resID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So basically it was just buggy code, that you needed help debugging. Next time, try to *isolate* the problem yourself. Ask yourself what could be wrong, then test just that. Here, it could have been the `for` loop, the `if` test, or the resID passed to `setImageResource`. StackOverflow is best used ***after*** you've tested each aspect of your code, and determined ***which*** line(s) don't work the way you expect. Then you would have a *specific* question, whose answer *would be useful to other people*. Here, what you had is "my code is broken and I don't know why". Solving it only helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your layout with the ImageView set, you can use View.setVisibility to show or hide the ImageView:

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);
if (key.equals("String"))    
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you want to change your image after you've inflated your layout, you can use

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is classic case of XY problem. Your real problem is to get resource id from string. which has been answered many time before on SO. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Try this:

```
final String splitedDouble[] = companyString.split(",,");

String[] arrayOfString = { "Beard Vape Co;beard_vape_co", "two;zwei", "three;drei" };


Hashtable<String, String> hashTable = new Hashtable<String, String>();
for(String s: arrayOfString){
    String[] array = s.split(";");
    String sKey ="", sValue="";
    if(array.length > 1){
        sKey = array[0]; sValue = array[1];
        hashTable.put(sKey, sValue);
        imageView.setImageResource(getResId("R.drawable." + sValue.toString(), Drawable.class));
        imageView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
        if(sKey.toString().equals(liquidCompany)){
            imageView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

public static int getResId(String resName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this when I put it in to my android studios there were quite a few things that I could not resolve or import

Comment: True. This isn't something I tested. Also I haven't added any imports. So I can imagine it had some unresolved symbols. But I hope it gave you enough information to point out the problem and arrive at solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your image didn't show is because here

```
imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt("R.drawable." + sValue.toString()));
```

You didn't set the right resource id of your image. `Integer.parseInt("R.drawable." + sValue.toString())` return an invalid identifier.

You can following the example below to do.

```
    Class<?> drawableClass = R.drawable.class;
    try {
        Field icLauncherField = drawableClass.getDeclaredField("ic_launcher");
        imageView.setImageResource(Integer.valueOf(icLauncherField.getInt(null)));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: would this still go inside of the loop?

Comment: Yes, you can do it inside the loop.

Comment: okay sounds good I shall give it a try real fast. Thank you guys for all of the help with this