# Android- Loop over IDs with Java

Tags: java, android

I wanted to find different `TextViews`, which are depending on an integer.

Let's say I have got three TextViews:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/text1" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/text2" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/text3" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in my **MainActivity** I have got following:

```
String resourceText = "R.id.text";
int textCounter = 1;
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(resourceText + textCounter);
```

So the result should be that I am able to access different TextViews over the textCounter but it doesn't work.

But using this code gives me an **error which says that the findViewByID function expects an integer.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, getting resource ID from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getIdentifier()` to convert string version of a resource id .
You just need to modify your code in this way.

```
String resourceText = "R.id.text";
int textCounter = 1;
textViewResId=getResources().getIdentifier(resourceText+textCounter, "id", getPackageName());
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(textViewResId);
```