# Optimize java assignments

Tags: java, android

I have some bindings that share the same root, Is there a way to shorten the code with a while loop that iterate across all of them?

```
RadioGroup G1, G2.. ... ...; // At class scope
TextView result1... .. ..; 


/** ... */
public void bindViews() {
    G1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    G2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    G3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);
    G4 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup4);
    G5 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup5);
    G6 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup6);
    G7 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup7);
    G8 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup8);
    G9 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup9);
    G10 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup10);
    G11 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup11);
    G12 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup12);
    G13 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup13);
    G14 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup14);
    G15 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup15);
    G16 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup16);
    G17 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup17);
    G18 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup18);
    G19 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup19);
    G20 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup20);
    ....
}
```

Can reflection be use to make this code less verbose? 
My interest is mostly to make it easier to **bind > 40** **RadioGroups** and **TextViews**.

Comment: I think a for loop would be more suitable here, actually.

Comment: in this case you can do it with a loop cause of incremental indexes but if you want something general, then story is different!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, getting resource ID from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
int count = 40;
RadioGroup G[] = new RadioGroup[count];
for(int i = 1 ; i < count ; i++){
   String temp = "radioGroup" + i;
   int id = getResources().getIdentifier(temp, "id", getPackageName());
   G[i] = (RadioGroup) findViewById(id);
 }
```

Comment: That's good, except `getResources().getIdentifier` is actually slower than the duplicate question flagged above

Comment: thanks @cricket_007, I didnt knew that. I will try to execute it first, then i will update my code. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShubhamNandanwar Any idea why id is -1?