# Add lots of Textviews

Tags: java, android, loops

I want to assign a lot of TextViews in code (272 in total):

```
texx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resul1);
texx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resul2);
texx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resul3);
texx4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resul4);
...
texx272 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resul272);
```

Any ideas on how I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Are the views fixed (fixed ids) inside a xml layout or dynamically created in code?

Comment: Don't understand the question. texx1 is never used in the layout while resul1 is, if that answers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option with using fixed ids and not having it statically typed as properties would be a list of TextView holding references to the views like this:

```
List<TextView> textviews = new ArrayList<>();
Resources res = getResources();

for (int i = 1; i <=272; i++) {

    int id = res.getIdentifier("resul" + i, "id", getContext().getPackageName());
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id);
    textviews.add(tv);
}
```

From here on you would have to access a list item in order to access the desired textview

```
TextView textViewToAccess = textViews.get(13);
textViewToAccess.setText(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has API to retrieve an id constant dynamically (by name): [Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string), it can be used to "mass-produce" these ids.
And for storing results, an array or a collection can be used.

Also, writing code that way would certainly make you an enemy of the guy who will have to maintain the code. A better idea would be to *think* twice, and come up with some better design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have **272** `TextViews`, all with separate id's?

You can get an int id by a string like this...

```
public static int getIdByName(String name) {
    return getResourceIdByName(name, "id");
}

public static int getResourceIdByName(String name, String type) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(context.getPackageName()).append(":").append(type).append("/").append(name);
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(s.toString(), null, null);
}
```

So for you, you could use the above and loop around all 272 TextViews and insert into a `List<TextView>` like this:

```
List<TextView> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 272; i++) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) getIdByName("resul" + i);
    results.add(textView);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a copy of my answer?

Comment: I answered before you ;-)

Comment: hmm... 20:17 vs 20:21? :)