# How to refer drawable file in JSON string using android

Tags: android, json

I have the android application that uses Json data and display the content in recyclerview but some of the images come from drawable file and i want to display those images in recyclerview using json  string

Anyone who know how to do that can help me

Comment: show what you did ?

Comment: what did you try so far show your effort?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string to get drawable from string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)