# I want to set drawables to ImageView as a part of database (with id, questions, answers and drawables names)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, imageview, drawable

I am completely amateur in programming. I've started to learn it a few days ago. It means,

```
mImageName.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.X));
```

where X is a name of drawable file, but for X I have to have:

```
mQuestionLibrary.getImage(mQuestionNumber);//the name of drawable
```

How to merge this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've obtained the solution.

```
mImageName.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/" + this.mQuestionLibrary.getImage(mQuestionNumber), null, getPackageName()));
```