# how to store image in an array in android

Tags: android

here is my java code
i want to store all the image in drawable folder and access it through recyclerview  so i created a list of array but it shows error missing ','

is getImages will return images

```
 public static int[] getImages() {
            int[] images =
                           {R.drawable.1,
                            R.drawable.2,
                            R.drawable.3,
                            R.drawable.4,
                            R.drawable.5,
                            R.drawable.6,
                            R.drawable.7,
                            R.drawable.8,
                            R.drawable.9,
                            R.drawable.10,
                            R.drawable.11};
            return images;
        }
```

Comment: Should use a loop to access those. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Comment: Which line shows the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource_name must not start with a number.

try using:

```
R.drawable._1 or R.drawable.img1
```

instead of

```
R.drawable.1
```

and rename the image accordingly.

Comment: is it return images

Answer (score 2):

You use a typed array in

> arrays.xml

file within your /res folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="images">
        <item>@drawable/image1</item>
        <item>@drawable/image2</item>
        <item>@drawable/image3</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

And get the array from your activity like this way :

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray images= res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
Drawable drawable = images.getDrawable(0);
```

**OR**

```
TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);

// get resource ID by index
images .getResourceId(i, -1)

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(i, -1));

// recycle the array
images.recycle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Android generates for every resource file a constant inside R.java - class. The file name defines the name of the constant field. Field and variables names can not begin with a number:

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".

[From: JavaDoc Variables - Naming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)