# No resource ID found, when resource exists

Tags: java, android, json, image

I am creating an app, that fetchs data from JSON, and i got stuck on one part: When i try to read my image from string to `ImageView`, i get error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
              Process: , PID: 9535
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource ID found for: i_coal / class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
                  at com.infonuascape.osrshelper.fragments.BankViewFragment.getResId(BankViewFragment.java:69)
                  at com.infonuascape.osrshelper.fragments.BankViewFragment$GetItems.doInBackground(BankViewFragment.java:100)
                  at com.infonuascape.osrshelper.fragments.BankViewFragment$GetItems.doInBackground(BankViewFragment.java:74)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: i_coal
                  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:890)
                  at .fragments.BankViewFragment.getResId(BankViewFragment.java:66)
                  at .fragments.BankViewFragment$GetItems.doInBackground(BankViewFragment.java:100) 
                  at .fragments.BankViewFragment$GetItems.doInBackground(BankViewFragment.java:74) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How can i fix it? The resource exists if i try to use R.Drawable.i_coal;
Also how can i check if the resource does not exist to skip it instead of throwing an error?

`BankViewFragment`:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class BankViewFragment {
private static final String TAG = "BankViewFragment";

private static Account account;
private ListView lv;
private ImageView iv;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ItemList;

public static BankViewFragment newInstance(final Account account) {
    BankViewFragment fragment = new BankViewFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(b);
    return fragment;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bank_view, null);
    ItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    new GetItems().execute();
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String nikas = sharedPref.getString("bankname", "null");
    return view;
}

public static int getResId(String resourceName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resourceName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No resource ID found for: "
                + resourceName + " / " + c, e);
    }
}

private class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("minescape", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nikas = sharedpreferences.getString("bankname",  "null");
        String url = "https://api.minesca.pe/game/classic/stats?username=" + nikas;
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "NIKAS: " + nikas);
        Log.e(TAG, "ACCOUNT: " + account);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONObject items = jsonObj.getJSONObject("bank");
                Iterator keys = items.keys();
                while(keys.hasNext()) {
                    String dynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
                    JSONObject line = items.getJSONObject(dynamicKey);
                    String item = line.getString("item");
                    Integer image = getResId(item, Drawable.class);
                    String amount = line.getString("amount");
                    Log.e(TAG, "DAIGTAS: " + item);
                    Log.e(TAG, "KIEKIS: " + amount);
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                    String itembank = item.replaceAll("i_", "");
                    String itembanks = itembank.replaceAll("_", " ");
                    contact.put("name", itembanks);
                    contact.put("email", amount);
                    ImageView ims = (ImageView) lv.findViewById(R.id.logo);
                    lv.setBackgroundResource(getResId(item, Drawable.class));
                    ItemList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                };

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), ItemList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "email","name"},
                new int[]{R.id.email, R.id.name});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

}
```

`list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:layout_width="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="219dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can get Resources using a string as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Comment: @kiel3 i have updated the code and the error i get! Thanks!

Comment: @RokasŠčesnavičius Hey, I am the one who created this project on Github and I keep receiving those crashes. Can you change your package name to something else? Also, are you planning on doing a pull request in the project? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 context.getResources().getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Comment: As Kiel3 said, i now got the image in string, but how to display it?

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().
         getIdentifier("drawable/apple", null, context.getPackageName()));