# Is it possible to setColorFilter to the imageView from Uri of values/colors?

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, uri

Is it possible to setColorFilter to the imageView from Uri of values/colors?

```
 ImageView imageView;
    String colorString = "colorBlack";
     colorResourceNameURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/values/colors/" + colorString.replace("\"", ""));

imageView.setColorFilter(colorResourceNameURI); //???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up a resource value based on a name; you don't necessarily need a URI. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093447/6759241) for a partial explanation:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(colorString.replace("\"", ""), "color", getPackageName());
imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(id));
```