# Android Studio: Is it possible to call resources via variables?

Tags: android, variables, resources

I have 9 color resources in my colors.xml called colorRand01, colorRand02 .... colorRand09.

In my java code, I call

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand01);
```

to change the color.

Now I have an int variable (lets call it i) and I want to do something like:

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource("R.color.colorRand0" + i);
```

Is this even possible in some way? At the moment my solution is this, but it would be great if I could make this shorter:

```
if(color == 1) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand01);
        }else if (color == 2) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand02);
        }else if (color == 3) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand03);
        }else if (color == 4) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand04);
        }else if (color == 5) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand05);
        }else if (color == 6) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand06);
        }else if (color == 7) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand07);
        }else if (color == 8) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand08);
        }else if (color == 9) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand09);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible abut then it should be relativeLayout.`setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand01 + i);` And the resource should exist of course.

Comment: `relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRand01 + color - 1);` But you should have added the resources in that sequence.

Comment: But maybe you better read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
int colorID = getResources().getIdentifier("colorRand0" + i, "color", getPackageName());
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(colorID);
```

Based on [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient
> to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

In addition to the above note, because you don't reference resources, in build time the resources may shrink as unused resources. Your app will crash when executing this code.