# How can I get drawable resource by string?

Tags: drawable, android-jetpack-compose

I have their name as String which is in drawable folder. How can I access to drawable folder and pass drawable resource to change the Icon View.

```
val iconList = ["ic_apple","ic_banana","ic_melon"]
```

and `ic_apple.png`, `ic_banana.png`, `ic_melon.png` in my drawable folder.

Like,
there was this with java's code.

```java
String name = "your_drawable";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
        
view.setBackground(drawable)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by "String which is in a drawable folder"? Strings are stored in the values resource and not drawables. And what do you mean by "Icon View"? Please update your post with more accurate information.

Comment: @Johann Update the post. Please check it out.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4428288/753632

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`LocalContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalContext()) to get current context, and then use same methods as you used in view based Android:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
val drawableId = remember(name) {
    context.resources.getIdentifier(
        name,
        "drawable",
        context.packageName
    )
}
Image(
    painterResource(id = drawableId),
    contentDescription = "..."
)
```

Comment: Use of getIdentifier is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code

Comment: @Darksymphony this is a reasonable warning, which says that you should use `R.drawable.ic_your_name` whenever it's possible - by doing this you'll get a build time warning when your resource is removed instead of a crash(or empty resource, not sure what'll happen on a wrong string). But this question is especially about getting resource by string - and yes, it's not safe in the first place, so you should only use it when you know what're you doing. A usage possible scenario is sending image name from the server.

Answer (score 0):

it will also work with the ressourceString

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
val text = stringResource(id = 
LocalContext.current.resources.getIdentifier(
    "Error_verification_code",
    "string",
    context.packageName
))
```