# How to fix use of getIdentifier is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations?

Tags: android, sqlite

I use sqlite I'm my app to store and retrieve names and and images. I use below code to get names of the images to show in the Recyclerview.

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Here I get this warning

```
 getIdentifier is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations
```

what is the replacement for this?

Before that I used image id instead of image name to store it in sqlite but it gets problems if I add or remove images from drawable as soon as project recompile again.
So, I figured it out that it's better to store images using image name instead of image id.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the replacement for this?

Maintain a `Map<String, Int>` to map your in-database identifiers to `R.drawable` contents. This has the added value of allowing you to rename your drawable resources without impacting the identifiers that you store in your database.

Comment: I used this solution by ( Daniel De León ), worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string/4428288#4428288