# I have an array contains string values, in that same name i have image in drawable.so i want to add in integer array how to do that?

Tags: android

I have an array contains string values, in that same name i have image in drawable.so i want to add in integer array how to do that? ex string newarray[]={"jj","kk","ll"};
i want to access R.drawable.jj ,R.drwable.kk,R.drawable.ll

Answer (score 2):

To access the drawables you need an int. Instead of saving the names in a String array, save the IDs in an int array:

```
int[] drawables = {R.drawable.jj, R.drawable.kk, R.drawable.ll};
```

Then all you need to do to access them is call:

```
getResources().getDrawable(drawables[0]);
```

Comment: i have n number of string values which am taking according to my list selection for example if i select firstitem array value will change.in that case how to do this

Comment: I think what he meant is what WarrenFaith answered.

Comment: I have four images in the Gallery View. When we do swipe from left to right or right to left the Gallery View moves all the images i.e if I swipe from left to right from the first image then it will move to all the four images. What I want is that when I swipe it should only move to the next image.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the [identifier by name](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Resources res = getResources();
res.getDrawable(res.getIdentifier(myStringArray[0], "drawable", myPackage));
```

A similar question was already answered: [get resource id by passing name as a parameter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/get-resource-id-by-passing-name-as-a-parameter-in-android)

Comment: I have four images in the Gallery View. When we do swipe from left to right or right to left the Gallery View moves all the images i.e if I swipe from left to right from the first image then it will move to all the four images. What I want is that when I swipe it should only move to the next image.

Comment: this is quite another question and I guess that it was already asked here. please search for it. A suggestion: If you implement the gesturedetector, you should be able to define how much the gallery should move. Anyway, search for it, I bet this was already asked and answered here...