# Android theme name from theme ID

Tags: android, themes

I need to know the name of the current theme, I already have the theme's resource ID. Anybody knows how to get the current **theme's name**?

Thanks

---

### Solution

```
public String getThemeName()
{
    PackageInfo packageInfo;
    try
    {
        packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        int themeResId = packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme;
        return getResources().getResourceEntryName(themeResId);
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using `getResourceEntryName()` or `getResourceName()` on `Resources` (typically retrieved via `getResources()`), depending on what you are aiming for.

Comment: More specifically `getResources().getResourceName(getApplicationInfo().theme)`

Answer (score 9):

Using `packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme` will return the theme for the entire app and not each activity. This is hacky, but should get the theme for the current activity/context:

```
public static String getThemeName(Context context, Resources.Theme theme) {
  try {
    int mThemeResId;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      Field fThemeImpl = theme.getClass().getDeclaredField("mThemeImpl");
      if (!fThemeImpl.isAccessible()) fThemeImpl.setAccessible(true);
      Object mThemeImpl = fThemeImpl.get(theme);
      Field fThemeResId = mThemeImpl.getClass().getDeclaredField("mThemeResId");
      if(!fThemeResId.isAccessible())fThemeResId.setAccessible(true);
      mThemeResId = fThemeResId.getInt(mThemeImpl);
    } else {
      Field fThemeResId = theme.getClass().getDeclaredField("mThemeResId");
      if(!fThemeResId.isAccessible())fThemeResId.setAccessible(true);
      mThemeResId = fThemeResId.getInt(theme);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      return theme.getResources().getResourceEntryName(mThemeResId);
    }
    return context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(mThemeResId);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Theme returned by application#getTheme() is always Theme.DeviceDefault
    return "Theme.DeviceDefault";
  }
}
```

I know this is an old question, but thought I would add my findings.

Comment: Why Theme returned by `getThemeName(application, application.getTheme())` is always `Theme.DeviceDefault` ? It's also `Theme.DeviceDefault` if I set `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to `application` tag

Comment: Doesn't work in Android 12: No field mThemeResId in class Landroid/content/res/ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl; (declaration of 'android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)

Answer (score -3):

try the below line of code to get the resource name from resource id

```
getResources().getString(resource id);
```

Refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name) you may get some ideas how to do

Comment: No, that returns the value of a string resource.