# How can I determine the name of the current theme set for the handset?

Tags: java, android, themes, default, android-theme

How can I determine the name of the current theme set for the handset? I do not make any changes to the theme or choose an XML file to apply a theme, as I use the default settings. I just need to know if the user has made any changes since the last time the program ran because I am saving the height and width of the available screen, and the button's border size. If any changes have been made on the handset, then maybe these saved values will be incorrect and need recalculating.

Comment: you can get the theme of your app .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302853/android-theme-name-from-theme-id

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks. Will checking to the if the theme name has changed or the current API has changed, be enough to accurately determine that the height and width of the available screen, and the button's border size have stayed the same?