# Xamarin: How to get current theme name in code?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-appcompat, android-theme

In Xamarin Android, how do I get the current theme name programmatically? I need to get the name as a string such as "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog".

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to the code bellow:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo;

packageInfo = PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(PackageName,PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
int themeResId = packageInfo.ApplicationInfo.Theme;
var name = Theme.Resources.GetResourceEntryName(themeResId);
```

And here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302853/android-theme-name-from-theme-id) about how to get theme name in Android project(using java)