# How to verify which theme a view is using

Tags: android, android-theme, android-testing

Android newbie here! I have an Activity class I'll call `SomeActivity`, which uses a theme `BlueTheme`:

```
<style name=“BlueTheme” parent="@style/AnotherTheme”>
  …
</style>
```

How can I verify that my activity is using the theme in a test? Activity has a `getTheme` method, but I'm struggling to find some way to identify which theme it is.

```
@Test
public void verifyTheme() {
    
  SomeActivity activity = setUpActivityControllerAndGetActivity();

  // This represents what I would like to do, but don’t know how
  String actualThemeName = activity.getTheme().getThemeName();

  assertThat(actualThemeName).isEqualTo(“BlueTheme”);
}
```

Comment: The answer found in the following link may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302853/android-theme-name-from-theme-id

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the resource id of the theme, so I'm not sure if those methods will work for me.