# getting id of button and performing operations in android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

in my android application there is group of buttons.i have given them id as b1,b2,b3...
and using random function i'm generating a number and by using that number i'm changing button image.
ex. if random number is 6.then i want to change image of button whose id is b6.
how can i create id b6 using integer 6 and b and perform operations on that button.

```
    String id;
    Random rand=new Random();
int num=rand.nextInt(9)+1;
id="b"+num;
```

but in android id of button is not in string format

Comment: Put your button resource ids into an array and then use your random number to select one of the array elements.

Comment: i tried it.Drawable id[]={b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9};   Drawable a = id[num].getBackground();
       
    if(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy).equals(a))
    
     but1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);

Comment: id[num].getBackground(); giving an error

Comment: of course - it's an int! you want to do `getBackground` on the button, not its ID. to do this you must find it by ID using `findViewById(id[num]).getBackground()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare an array with all the button IDs like that:

```
int[] buttonIds = new int[] {R.b1, R.b2, ...};
```

and use it to access the ID of a random button:

```
num = rand.nextInt(buttonIds.length);
int buttonId = buttonIds[num];
findViewById(buttonId).doSomething();
```

But it'll be tedious if the number of buttons becomes large or isn't constant. But for small numbers that seems fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

The Resources class has this method:

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Have a look at it.

Comment: also similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name