# Reference drawable from string-array in android

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable, arrays

how would I reference a drawable resource from the string xml file?
I want to do

```
<string-array name="my_array">
<item>@drawable/my_image</item>
...
```

How would I do that?

Comment: What would that even mean? A drawable is not a string, so how could it be part of a string array?

Comment: That is kind of possible, if you store the names you can get the resources from a `Resources` object. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name

Answer (score 15):

for arrays of drawables ids, don't use string array just use `<array>`

then to use them, get a `TypedArray` if the ids

```
TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.my_image_ids);
int resourceId = images.getResourceId(id, -1);
```

and don't forget when you're done with the resource id and array to recycle it

```
images.recycle();
```

Comment: Great answer, but it was hard to find. There are so many similar answers and questions.

Comment: I'd recommend using 0 as the default instead of -1. 0 will never be returned as it is reserved to designate a missing (null) resource, whereas -1 is a valid id value. Although the build will not automatically assign -1, it is still considered a valid id, and it is common to use such values when assigning ids programmatically (for example, in wrapping adapters), in order to avoid collisions with the range of integers that could be assigned automatically during the build.

Comment: Perfect, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are trying to store all of your image resource names (as string) inside an array and be called when you write your java code?

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] images = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
```

Would get your string array into an array. You can get the item you want by accessing the array as usual.

```
String image_name = images[0];
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

If you are trying to achieve to load a list of images to a gridview, you might want to refer to this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

They have placed the array in the base adapter, like this:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

Which you can easy use just like how you would access an array.