# How to list Android string resources in an array

Tags: android

I want to do something similar to this as explained in [Reference drawable from string-array in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791845/reference-drawable-from-string-array-in-android)

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

I tried this .java file :

```
    int[] descriptions = new int[] { 
        R.string.description_section1, 
        R.string.description_section2, 

    };
```

but it doesn't seem to be the right syntax.

Comment: May I ask you what's wrong in using a strin array **as a reource**? You'd have the array already set in a resource file...

Comment: I want to reference in CODE and make a loop with the array

Comment: You can do so also with a string array set in xml and then retrieved in code...

Comment: I don't want to do so in XML I want to use code like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791845/reference-drawable-from-string-array-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
int[] descriptions = { 
    R.string.description_section1, 
    R.string.description_section2, 

};
```

Comment: @BobMalooga Because this compiles just fine, I think the extra comma at the last element is optional. But I don't know where this is specified.

Answer (score 3):

define your array in array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="descriptions">
        <item>section1</item>
        <item>section1</item>
    </string-array>
 </resources>
```

then try this:

```
String[] descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.descriptions);
```

Comment: ... Exactly what I proposed.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative though I'm not fond of XML