# How to get access to object

Tags: java, android

I am new to java.
I have a directory with a txt file (R.raw). I want to get access with a command

```
InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.itemname);
```

where `itemname` is a dynamic string with a filename from a previous activity.

How do I can get open file in `R.raw` by a string "n0.txt"?

In javascript I can implement it like R.raw["n0.txt"] or R.raw.itemname.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write here the object please.. We need more details.. It is not clear

Comment: Your question is quite misleading.What do you mean by R.raw includes n0.txt and n1.txt ?

Comment: please send us your code..details are not clear

Comment: I am afraid he's talking about a serialized object

Comment: If it's just a POJO, it probably has some getters you can call.  In any case, you need to edit your question to show us what `R.raw` ***is***.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to read the file called `itemname` (in this case `n0.txt`) in the `R.raw` directory?

Comment: @azurefrog yes, you right

Answer (score 0):

You need to use method [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
Context context;
Resources res;

int itemId = res.getIdentifier("itemname", "raw", context.getPackageName());
InputStream is = res.openRawResource(itemId);
```

Original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/1891118).

Comment: get an error ( how open txt file based on filename received from first activity ? can you give a link?

Comment: make sure you don't add file extension! ``"itemname.txt"`` is **wrong**, but ``"itemname"`` is correct