# String array with drawable values to int array

Tags: android, arrays, string, int, drawable

I am building an Andorid application. I have this String array which contains the values for the image files:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[]{ "R.drawable.image1", "R.drawable.image2 ", "R.drawable.image3", "R.drawable.image4"};
```

Is is it possible to convert the stringArray to something like that, if yes h so the Android app can read the resource values properly ? If yes then how ?

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};
```

Comment: but the first one is not a String,

Comment: Not only **it's possible**, but **it really should be** like that. Because R ids are stored as **int**s, not as strings.

Comment: Your stringArray line shouldn't compile

Comment: I added the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the identifiers if you know the resource type. Maybe just tokenize the string and get the type, then call one of theese methods answered here:
[How to get a resource id with a known resource name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name)