# How to get ID of imagebutton when it is clicked

Tags: android, imagebutton

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.a :
        String textans = ans.getText().toString();
        ans.setText(textans +id);
    }
}
```

I am creating an android application in which i have 5 `ImageButton`s and a `TextView`.

`ImageButton`s are having alphabet images i.e A, B, C, D, E and their ID's in XML are a, b, c, d, e as follows

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:src="@drawable/b" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:src="@drawable/c" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:src="@drawable/d" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/e"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/a"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/a"
        android:src="@drawable/e" />
```

What I want is when I click an `ImageButton` the respective letter must be set in `TextView`. For this purpose I have used a `switch` in `onClick` method and tended to get the ID of the button and set it in `TextView` but id is something in `int`.

My question is this "How can I get the name of the ID of button clicked". For example when Iclick button having image A, the id of `ImageButton` is "**a**", so it must be stored in a variable and then it is set to `TextView`.

Hopefully my question is much clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the **ID** of the clicked button to your `TextView` you could use something like this

```
String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resId);
```

> Use in your solution

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.a:
            String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
            textView.setText(resourceName);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i used resource thing but i got  "com.example.app_name:id/a"

Comment: i only wnt to set TextView with it ID "a".

Comment: You should call `getResourceEntryName()`, instead of `getResourceName()`.

Comment: you helped me alot.i was stuck there and you show me the way thanks again.well i want to get more help from you. Can i add you on facebook?

Comment: @cuteprogrammer welcome, accept the answer, so that the question is resolved (green arrow next to the answer). I am not using Facebook. You can ask a question here and link it  to me and i'll take a look.

Comment: You can post it to this answer and i'll see it. Or we could talk in stackoverflow chatroom, or skype.

Comment: I have another question related to this question.

Comment: @cuteprogrammer talk to me.

Comment: i have accessed ID of ImageButton using reference, now i want to access that ImageButton using the ID.

Comment: @cuteprogrammer check the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name). You can use `getIdentifier` to get the resource reference from resource name. And when you have the resource  reference, you can get the ImageButton.

Comment: What i was doing that when an ImageButton of letter in clicked then the ID of that Button in set in the textView and that button is set to invisible.
Now i want when the last character of string in textview is accessed (which is the ID of the ImageButton) that ImageButton must be visible again.

Comment: Easy, use the approach that I explained above your last post. It should work, if you get the resource name, you can get the resource reference, meaning you can get the View, meaning you can set the visibility :).

Comment: resID= this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfResource", "id", this.getPackageName());
 should i use this? sorry may be it is a silly question but what to type in parameters of getIdentiifier(" ", " ". "packgename") ???

Comment: @cuteprogrammer I haven't tried it before, but something like this could work `int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("resourceName", "id", getPackageName());`

Comment: and what next? plz guide me completely because i am practicing android :( .

Comment: @cuteprogrammer if you get the resource ID reference to your view (with the use of `getIdentifier`), you can call `ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resId);` and voila, you should have it.