# Android Getting resource string based on runtime value

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Is there a way to get a specific resource from my "strings.xml" based on runtime value?

To explain more, I have a list of values, i.e. taxi fares for each location - i.e. different for Bangalore, Chennai, etc.

my Strings.xml looks something like this:

```
<string-array name="Bengaluru">
    <item>Min Fare | 100</item>
    <item>Per KM Fare |10</item>
    </string-array>
```

In my MainActivity, I'm using code like this:

```
String currentCity = <Getting the city via phone location method>
if(currentCity.equals("Bengaluru")) {

    // My method to extract values from the string
    myCustomParser(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Bengaluru));
}
```

(I probably will replace if with Switch-Case, but isn't there a way to rewrite the above as:

```
  // My method to extract values from the string
    myCustomParser(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currentCity));
```

i.e. dynamic replacement of the value I want to pull out from the resource file?

Thanks

Comment: You should not use `==` for String comparison. Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/1435985) should get you on the right track on how to look up a resources id by its name if you wanted to go that route.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a resource id with a known resource name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).
Example of usage:

```
myCustomParser(getResources().getStringArray(
    getResources().getIdentifier("Bengaluru", "array", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more clear than the duplicate answer