# Save R.id.content as content of a Variable Android

Tags: java, android

currently I am writing a Class in Java for Android. Basically, I am using this piece of code, `R.id.content`, a ton. Now, I was wondering, sense the `content` part of it may change at any time, how could I write this so I would only have to change it in one place? I was thinking I could do something like the following:

```
public {unknown data-type} varName = R.id.content;
```

But then I realized that this is actually a class, so then I was wondering if I could write it like this:

```
public {unknown data-type} varName = content;
.... R.id.varName;
```

Problem is I am not exactly sure on how I would do that either. So simply, my question is, how could I write `R.id.content` so I can easily change the `content` part of it (like put the `content` in to a variable)?

Comment: You should take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name

Comment: Thank you, I was not exactly sure what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your R.id.content has an integer value(In the R file under id subclass). So you could store the whole thing in an **int** variable. Like this :

```
int your_variable=R.id.content;
```

OR

```
int[] your_array=new int[]{R.id.c1,R.drawable.p1};
```

and use it like you would normally use a variable.
Eg :

```
EditText edt=(EditText)findViewbyId(your_variable);
```

Is this what you were looking for..?