# Set R.string.someString with a variable

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to somehow do this following:

```
view.setIconResource(getString(R.string.wi_alien));
```

...in a way like this?

```
String someString = "wi_alien";
view.setIconResource(getString(R.string.someString));
```

The part below does not work obviously, you get the "cannot resolve symbol String". Is something like this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/115145

Comment: No, you need to set Resources before compiling

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you!

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you!