# How to access images from drawable folder in android studio according to my choice?

Tags: android, image, drawable

Suppose I have a list of item like String[] list={"item1","item2","item3",....,"itemN"}; I have corresponding images of each item having different formats(some in jpg,some in png etc.) and different names serially(as indices of list array) in drawable folder. I have to do some processing on the list array & each time it returns some particular & different indices of list.
So,I have to show the corresponding images of those items indicated by returned indices no as list view in android studio. how can I do this.
For example, If after processing I have indices no: { 3,7,1}, I have to show corresponding no of images for item3, item7 and item1 stored in drawable folder as listView. Again,indicated indices values may change depending on processing on it.

I want that [here in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xikk.png) the sequence of displaying the images and texts will not be according to 'position',rather it will be according to my choice like in first row position of listview I will have the image of item3,in row position 2 ->image of item 7,in row position 3 -> image of item 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your List Array processing class, define a Int array containing references to the images:

```
int imageRes[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,...};
```

Now considering that only three indices are returned after processing:
ex: 
    indices[] ={1,5,6};
    int imageArray[] - (Size can be three)

```
for(int i =0; i<3;i++){
imageArray[i] = imageRes[indices[i]];
}
```

Your ListView can contain one Image View. Create a custom adapter for the list view and pass imageArray as parameter.

Then you can set the Image for ImageView something like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource[imageArray[i]]
```

Comment: yeah! I was thinking this way,Hope it will work.going to try :)

Answer (score 0):

Store the R value of image in integer array and you can post according to indices from that array

```
int _rImage[] ={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ResourceId by name try something like

`int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());`

see [How to get a resource id with a known resource name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name)