# Resource naming reference

Tags: java, android, android-resources

In my android app, I have 9 buttons with the following reference:

```
R.id.button1;
R.id.button2;
....
R.id.button9
```

If I have an int value, lets say `int i` which holds the button number, is there a simple way for me to call the reference such as

```
String s = "R.id.button" + Integer.toString(i);
Button btn = (Button) findViewbyId(s);
```

My code is gettting way to verbose by doing 9 if checks. Thanks!

Comment: earlier answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476447/3482621 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/3482621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this to get the Button Object from String value,

```
String s = "button" + i;
int viewId = getResources().getIdentifier( s, "id", getPackageName());

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(viewId);
```