# Array Name passing variable

Tags: android

Let say I have 2 arrays

```
Array1 = 1,2,3,4,5
Array2 = a,b,c,d,e
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Array1);
```

That's work fine. But I don't want to use the code above again with another line

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Array2);
```

How do I get the below lines to work if
I had declared xxx as variable for array name

```
String xxx = Array1;
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.xxx);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
int xxx = R.array.Array1; //change to integer

String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(xxx); //pass the whole id
```

Instead of passing just the name of the resource, pass the whole ID (as integer).

**If you still want to pass the name as string**, you can:

```
String xxx = "Array1";
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xxx, "array", getPackageName());
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);
```

reference of the second option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476447/9038584

Comment: I understand your point to pass ID as integer.
However, the xxx variable is a string declared from some other method.
   'int xxx = R.array.Array1; //change to integer'
This won't work

Comment: I still want to pass the value using string name

Comment: I've updated my answer. This question already existed, refer to my link on my second option answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple util method in your activity or service:

```
String[] getArray(int id) {
    return getResources().getStringArray(id);
}
```

Usage:

```
String[] array1 = getArray(R.array.array1);
```